# Child Admin route is not being generated - Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I'm trying to set up an Admin as a child of an other Admin in Sonata Admin Bundle.

I have 2 Admin classes:

- **CategoryAdmin**
  This class contains the following method

  ```php
  protected function configureSideMenu(MenuItemInterface $menu, $action, AdminInterface $childAdmin = null)
  {            
       $id = $this->getRequest()->get('id');

       $menu->addChild(
           $this->trans('Projects'),
           array('uri' => $this->getChild('sonata.admin.project')->generateUrl('list', array('id' => $id)))
       );
  }
  ```
- **ProjectAdmin**
  This class contains `protected $parentAssociationMapping = 'category';`
  `category` is the property in the model class representing the ManyToOne association.

I added the following lines to my service configuration for CategoryAdmin

```php
calls:
    - [ addChild, ["@sonata.admin.project"]]
```

The routes for the child Admin are not being generated with this configuration. The link in the SideMenu (top menu) points to `/admin/project/list?childId=1&id=1`

Here is the output of the children of `CategoryAdmin` with `dump()`

```php
array:1 [▼
    "sonata.admin.project" => ProjectAdmin {#406 ▶}
]
```

This means that the configuration for my child admin seems to be correct. I have no idea, why the routes for the child admin are not being generated.

I hope somebody can give me a hint, what the problem could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the $baseRouteName and $baseRoutePattern overriden in your admin class ?

If you do, Sonata will generate both child and parent routes with the same name resulting in the parent routes overriding the child ones.

Comment: Is there no way around this? I have to define `$baseRouteName` and `$baseRoutePattern` because otherwise Sonata balks at my vendorless bundle (e.g. src/AppBundle/ )

Comment: If using the dev-master version of the SonataAdminBundle is not a problem, the bug was solved in it (https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/3250).

If not you can override the getBaseRoutePattern and getBaseRouteName to fix the behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Note for next gen sonata coders:
If your route is not being generated, first check you didn't do:

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    //clear all routes except given !!!
    $collection->clearExcept(array('list', 'show'));
}
```

It costs me two days...

Comment: Probably just saved me a couple of days!

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this issue while solving the problem for myself and decided to share the solution, which costed me several debugging hours...

The only way to generate a proper uri in this case is to use **low-level `routeGenerator`** which doesn't make any sonata suggestions, made inside `generateMenuUrl` method.

First you have to debug the routes, you have in your app (including autogenerated by sonata).

> php bin/console debug:router

For example I have 3 nesting levels

> **hall -> seats scheme -> sector**

And my routes are following:

```
  adminHall_list                             ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/hall/list
  adminHall_create                           ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/hall/create
  adminHall_edit                             ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/hall/{id}/edit
  adminHall_delete                           ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/hall/{id}/delete
  adminHall_adminScheme_list                 ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/hall/{id}/scheme/list
  adminHall_adminScheme_create               ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/hall/{id}/scheme/create
  adminHall_adminScheme_edit                 ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/hall/{id}/scheme/{childId}/edit
  adminHall_adminScheme_delete               ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/hall/{id}/scheme/{childId}/delete
  adminHall_adminScheme_adminSector_list     ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/hall/{id}/scheme/{childId}/sector/list
  adminHall_adminScheme_adminSector_create   ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/hall/{id}/scheme/{childId}/sector/create
  adminHall_adminScheme_adminSector_edit     ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/hall/{id}/scheme/{childId}/sector/{childChildId}/edit
  adminHall_adminScheme_adminSector_delete   ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/hall/{id}/scheme/{childId}/sector/{childChildId}/delete
```

In admin classes baseRouteName and baseRoutePattern has been overridden.

```
// HallSchemeAdmin.php
$this->baseRouteName = 'adminScheme';
$this->baseRoutePattern = 'scheme';
```

To generate a most **deep listing url**:

```
$url = $admin->getRouteGenerator()->generate('adminHall_adminScheme_adminSector_list', [
    'id' => $admin->getRequest()->get('id'),
    'childId' => 555, // put required id
]);
```

It will produce the url like this:

`/admin/hall/495/scheme/555/sector/list`

If you need **edit url**, you have to provide `childChildId` param too:

```
$url = $admin->getRouteGenerator()->generate('adminHall_adminScheme_adminSector_edit', [
    'id' => $admin->getRequest()->get('id'),
    'childId' => 555, 
    'childChildId' => 12345 
]);
```

The result is:
`/admin/hall/495/scheme/555/sector/12345/edit`